# Zend routes.ini with multiple params

Tags: php, url, zend-framework, routes

I have created a new route for my page in routes.ini (Zend 1.12):

```
; voyants
routes.voyants-order.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route"
routes.voyants-order.route = "voyants_liste/:order/:page"
routes.voyants-order.defaults.module = front
routes.voyants-order.defaults.controller = voyants
routes.voyants-order.defaults.action = index
routes.voyants-order.defaults.page = 1 
routes.voyants-order.reqs.page = \d+ 
routes.voyants-order.reqs.order = \w+
routes.voyants-order.reverse = "voyants_liste/%s/%s"
```

The url with order and page number params works fine : mysite.com/voyants_liste/support/2 for example, but the initial url dose not work mysite.com/voyants_liste , and i got an exception

> Exception information:
>
> Message: Invalid controller specified (voyants_liste)

Any ideas ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i juste needed some defaults values for my params :

```
routes.voyants-order.defaults.page = 1 
routes.voyants-order.defaults.order = nom
```

Thanks :)